# Converting a URI path to a relative file system path in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, path, uri

How do I convert an absolute or relative URI path (e.g. `/foo/bar.txt`) to a (segmentwise) corresponding relative file system path (e.g. `foo\bar.txt`) in .NET?

My program is not an ASP.NET application.

Comment: It may have made more sense for me to use a relative URI path as an example.

Answer (score 81):

Have you already tried `Server.MapPath`? 
or `Uri.LocalPath` property? Something like following :

```
string uriString = "file://server/filename.ext";
// Lesson learnt - always check for a valid URI
if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uriString))
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
    Console.WriteLine(uri.LocalPath);
}
```

Comment: Well, i had to modify this code to use this fragment instead
Console.WriteLine(uri.LocalPath + Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Fragment))
this is due # character in filenames

Answer (score 11):

I figured out this way to produce a full absolute file system path from a relative or absolute URI and a base path.

With:

```
Uri basePathUri = new Uri(@"C:\abc\");
```

**From a relative URI:**

```
string filePath = new Uri(basePathUri, relativeUri).AbsolutePath;
```

**From an absolute URI:**

```
// baseUri is a URI used to derive a relative URI
Uri relativeUri = baseUri.MakeRelativeUri(absoluteUri);
string filePath = new Uri(basePathUri, relativeUri).AbsolutePath;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
var localPath = Server.MapPath("/foo/bar.txt");
```

[See MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

Comment: My program is not an ASP.NET application, how do I get access to the Server object?

Comment: @acdx - I'm confused then...relative to what, a running application?  Your question is tagged `uri`, so I'm confused if it's not web, explain?

Comment: I'd like to get a relative file path, such as `foo\bar.txt`, that I can pass to `Path.Combine` to create an absolute file path.

Comment: @acdx - Relative means in relation to...in relation to **what** is the question, you're asking about a URI, but saying it's not web...this makes no sense and needs some clarification.  For starters, if not a web app, what **are** you running?

Comment: My application is a regular .NET console application. I want to map a URI to a file system path. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to convert the URI path to a relative file system path and then pass it to `Path.Combine` along with a base path like `C:\abc\` to form an absolute file system path. About terminology, a relative path by definition doesn't contain information about what it relates to.

Comment: @acdx - But, the thing figuring out what it relates to...it's relative to that, and you left that out of the question.  A URI can go 20 places, is it on the same machine, running IIS?  If none of the answers already posted here help, I'm at a loss to figure out what you're doing...a more detailed question is in order.  Try updating with an input and result example, that'd be much more helpful.

Comment: "But, the thing figuring out what it relates to...it's relative to that, and you left that out of the question."

Could you please rephrase that first sentence, I don't understand it at all.

My program is concerned with taking a forward-slash-separated URI path as input (example given in question), and producing a backslash-separated relative file system path with the same path segments as output (example given in question). This relative output path could, if desired, then be combined with a base path on some machine to yield an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

Not all have access to server.MapPath due to backend or framework changes, and there are lot's of way one of them is could be like this

```
public enum FileLocation
{
    NotSet,
    Disk,
    Resource,
}

private static readonly string[] FileExtenstions = new[] {
    ".js"
    ,".ts"
    ,".vue"
    ,".css"
    ,".jpg"
    ,".png"
    ,".gif"
    ,".ico"
    ,".svg"
    ,".ttf"
    ,".eot"
    ,".ttf"
    ,".woff"
    ,".woff2"
    ,".mp4"
    ,".mp3"
    ,".emf"
};

public FileLocation IsMappedTo(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));
    }
    //make sure we support .net default URI contract
    if (uri.IsFile)
        return FileLocation.Disk;

    //now assume you are looking in a web application
    var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
    if (path.Length == 0 || path.Equals("/",StringComparison.Ordinal) || path.Length< FileExtenstions.Min(s=>s.Length))
        return FileLocation.NotSet;

    //get the directory normally one would use IWebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath different versions .net will have other methods
    var dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");

    //get all resources names from the assembly hosting this class out side if the loop from this assembly you can also use
    //you can also use GetManifestResourceNames() to use the web application's assembly
    var resourceNames = new HashSet<string>(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames());
    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    if (entryAssembly != null && entryAssembly != this.GetType().Assembly)
    {
        foreach (var entry in entryAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry))
                resourceNames.Add(entry);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < FileExtenstions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (FileExtenstions[i].Equals(path[FileExtenstions[i].Length..], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || path.Contains(FileExtenstions[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //exists on disk
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, path.Replace("/", @"\", StringComparison.Ordinal))))
                return FileLocation.Disk;

            //has a file as an embedded resource with the same name (ignores the path) so you might have duplicates names
            if (resourceNames.Any(a => a.EndsWith(path.Split('/')[^1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                return FileLocation.Resource;
        }
    }

    return FileLocation.NotSet;
}
```

after this you just do:

```
switch (IsMappedTo(url))
{
    case FileLocation.NotSet:
        break;

    case FileLocation.Disk:
        break;

    case FileLocation.Resource:

        break;
}
```