# C# getting path from uri

Tags: c#, path, uri

My image has Uri with this value:

/word/media/image4.emf

How can I get the real path value from that?

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "real path"?

Comment: Real path means something like: "C\Users\John\Desktop\folder\image4.emf"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Yaur this is about picture with hyperlink. My image isn't on the internet.

Comment: @Srcee: Thats called an `absolute path`.

Comment: @Srcee: Can't you use [Uri.LocalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx)..?

Comment: -1 . @Scree, please try to edit your question with all your comments (and preferably with actual problem you are trying to solve). So far Abbas answer is as good as it can get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a URI path to a relative file system path in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442157/converting-a-uri-path-to-a-relative-file-system-path-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to get the absolute path of an image file. For this, you can use the LocalPath property of Uri class. See this for details; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Server.MapPath() method for the physical path. For more information on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: Then use the LocalPath property for the URI, more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath(v=vs.80).aspx